# Can I use in wysiwyg component v-validate required option?

Tags: vuejs2, wysiwyg

In my Laravel 5.8 / vuejs 2.6 app I use
 "vue-wysiwyg": "^1.7.2" and "vee-validate": "^2.2.5" and search a way to use in wysiwyg component v-validate
 options, like:

```
<wysiwyg v-model="hostelRow.descr" v-validate="'required'" id="descr" name="descr" />
```

the line above required does not work...

Comment: No I did not find

Comment: I found a solution with `Quasar` framework. You might find inspiration. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73957727/quasar-wysiwyg-q-editor-validation-rules-and-styles