# Quasar WYSIWYG q-editor validation rules and styles

Tags: validation, styles, vuejs3, wysiwyg, quasar-framework

I hava a form with WYSIWYG field and I use Quasar's [`q-editor`](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/editor#introduction) element. I want to add validation to that field with rules and styles similar to other fields like [`q-input`](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/input#validation), [`q-select`](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/select#introduction) etc.

Sample for q-input validation is:

```
<q-input v-model="model" label="Name" :rules="[val => !!val || 'Field is required']" />
```

Result:
[image]

This example for required WYSIWYG field doesn't work:

```
<q-editor v-model="editor" min-height="5rem" :rules="[val => !!val || 'Field is required']" />
```

There are similar questions [here](https://forum.quasar-framework.org/topic/7904/wysiwyg-q-editor-lazy-rules) and [here (with one posible solution)](https://forum.quasar-framework.org/topic/7904/wysiwyg-q-editor-lazy-rules).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually Quasar logic is to use [`q-field`](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/field#validation) wrapper element. Maybe it is a good idea to be added as desctription in [`q-editor`](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/editor#introduction) page.

That I do is wrap `q-editor` in `q-field`. When `q-editor` is in `template #control` on `q-field`, `val` for validation `val => !!val || 'Field is required'` is the content of `q-editor`. Maybe the reason is that the v-model is same for the two elements.

The problem is when validation failed, then the border of the `q-field` becomes red, and not of the `q-editor`. For this problem I use solution from the [second link](https://forum.quasar-framework.org/topic/7904/wysiwyg-q-editor-lazy-rules) in the question - added custom style to border of `q-editor` and `q-field` is `borderless`.

```
<q-field ref="fieldRef" v-model="editor" label-slot borderless
      :rules="[val => (!!val && val !== '<br>') || 'Field is required']" >
      <template #label>Description</template>
      <template #control>
        <q-editor v-model="editor" min-height="5rem" class="full-width"
          :style="fieldRef && fieldRef.hasError ? 'border-color: var(--q-negative)' : ''"/>
      </template>
    </q-field>
```

Result:
[image]

Here is the [CodePen example](https://codepen.io/MorticiaAddams/pen/RwyBKYR?editors=1011).

Comment: Great answer, thanks! The style attribute can be modified to be more generic: `border-color: var(--q-negative)`

Comment: Thank you for the note. I replaced `#C10015` with `var(--q-negative)` in my answer.